# I need to search a string of DNA for the pattern GGG + N(1-7) + GGG + N(1-7) + GGG

Tags: python-3.x, bioinformatics

Where N = either an A,C,T or G nucleotide. 
There are between 1 and 7 'N' nucleotides between each GGG.
I've not sure how to deal with the 'N' as it can be 1 of 4 bases as well the unkown number of them.

Answer (score 0):

If just the "N" part of this is troubling you, then try the below pattern when you regex.

```
pattern = '[ACTG]{1,7}'
```

This should match/search etc whatever value of N there is plus the GGG. If you don't want to match the GGG and know that there are at least 4 bases, replace 1 with 4.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly this soundsl ike what your wanting is a regex expression. I'm not familiar enough with python but I imagine you'd want to parallelize a scan. I did some bioinformatics in C++ but we were searching for known strings, and if you did hash based methods 3 bases is a bit to small to key off imo given GGG will have millions of repeats within a genome.

```
import re
matches = re.search('GGG.{1,7}GGG.{1,7}GGG',genome)
```

Even than that doesn't handle a 'sliding'window approach. AKA would you want it to return 2 results if the input was GGG + N(1-7) + GGG + N(1-7) + GGG + N(1-7) + GGG notice the 3rd N(1-7) + GGG repetition?

For that you probably want

```
import re
matches = re.search('GGG(.{1,7}GGG){2,}',genome)
```

then do a second pass over the results to find them. This approach while 'easy' requires quite a bit of memory since it will create substrings so large genomes will run into a bit of a problem.

Next optimization would be making your own pattern analyzer that doesn't waste gobs of memory and lets you search a partial substring without duplicating the string data. Having multiple copies of a genome in memory can be incredibly expensive when it is uncompressed text.

The problem lends itself well to mult-threading though if you can target sub-strings of the genomes.